# Too Few Arguments & Expected A Declaration

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with a game hack that makes the character auto jump for faster movement and I may sound very to dumb to what easy of an error it probably is so if anyone could help me that would be much appreciated!

```
#include <Windows.h>

Memory Mem;

#define key_space 0x20
#define key9 0x39
#define key_sc 0x0A
void bhopFunc();

const DWORD localBase = 0xA6C90C;
const DWORD flagOffset = 0x100;

void bhopFunc() {
    int FL_ONGROUND = 257; 
    Mem.Process("csgo.exe"); 
    DWORD ClientDLL = Mem.Module("client.dll"); 
}


if (GetAsyncKeyState(key_space) & 0x8000 && m_fFlags == FL_ONGROUND) { 
    keybd_event(KEY9, KEY9SC, 0, 0);

    keybd_event(KEY9, KEY9SC, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

    int main()
    {
        while (true) {
            bhopFunc();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What function does your `if` statement belong to?  Please check your `{` and `}`, match them up carefully. *Hint:  statements should be in a function and not free-standing.*

Comment: Off topic: Forward declaration of `void bhopFunc();` is unnecessary.

Comment: `if` statements cannot occur outside of a function

Answer (score 0):

The 4 lines of code above `int main()` are supposed to be inside your `bhopFunct()` function.

Here is your code fixed:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#define key_space 0x20
#define key9 0x39
#define key_sc 0x0A
void bhopFunc();

const DWORD localBase = 0xA6C90C;
const DWORD flagOffset = 0x100;

void bhopFunc() {
    int FL_ONGROUND = 257;
    Mem.Process("csgo.exe");
    DWORD ClientDLL = Mem.Module("client.dll");

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(key_space) & 0x8000 && m_fFlags == FL_ONGROUND)
    {
        keybd_event(KEY9, KEY9SC, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(KEY9, KEY9SC, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true) 
    {
        bhopFunc();
    }
}
```